# It actually isn't Hanukkah yet. Anywhere

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, time

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245302/why-are-people-earning-the-gelt-hat-today - the Gelt hat can be awarded when it's December 16th *somewhere*. However, Chanukah (my preferred transliteration), being a Jewish holiday, starts at *night*. That's 25 Kislev on the Hebrew calendar.

If the hat is for Chanukah, it shouldn't be awarded based on the Gregorian calendar. It should be awarded based on the Jewish calendar.

Comment: Dates and times are hard.  That's why all of the date/time stuff is approximated.  The whole point is *not* to be exact about the times.

Comment: @hichris123 No. I know about the time leeway. I'm talking about it's got the wrong date.

Comment: @Scimonster [Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer) Besides, hats don't usually trigger halfway though a day, sooo...

Comment: Hat's aren't meant to be be _observances_ of holidays; they are _acknowledgments_ of them. Besides, I'm sure that sometimes, for practical reasons, gelt is sent a bit early. I know that I've already got a stack of presents under my Christmas tree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The hats are meant to be fun for everyone and introductions to traditions around the world. They are not meant to be *exactly matched* to those traditions.

As such, the 16th-ish definition is *good enough*.

If it makes you feel better, [Saint Lucia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245255/why-is-the-hat-called-st-lucia) is on December 13th, not 15th. Imagine getting Hanukkah wrong by *48 hours*.

Comment: To further this answer: a lot of people don't even know that much about the holiday or when it starts. A *date* that it does start on is a **lot** easier to explain in a short description of a hat than an exact time on that date.